# App (using sprite kit) crashes after returning from facebook ios sdk log in

Tags: ios, facebook, sprite-kit

Still having some problems with Facebook log in in my app.
I made a new view controller just for log in into Facebook. It works fine ad log in button appears. Problem is that when I am clicking log in button sometimes everything works fine and I  log in with Facebook and Facebook app closes and my view appears. But sometimes my app just crashes or it restarts itself. But when I return into my Facebook log in view I am connected with Facebook so log in was successful. 
I am not sure if it restarts but maybe just wrong view appears (not my Facebook log in view but app starter view).

===

Edit: It seems the app crashes due to an error/bug? in sprite kit

[image]

Comment: I guess your app doesn't crash but is killed for using too much memory. but without any more info nobody can say for sure

Comment: please update the question with relevant information -- e.g. crash report

Comment: My app does not have crash report it just stops and on left side list of Threads appears. On Thread 1 I get a ! ? I don't really understand this jet?

Comment: Post a screenshot of you Xcode when you debug it

Comment: If your app crashes then XCode would have printed log. Post it here.

Comment: @Daij-Djan http://s28.postimg.org/hus9prmst/Screen_Shot_2014_09_03_at_17_52_25.png

Comment: ir crashed due to some sprite kit error. expand the stack trace. slider in lower-left corner

Comment: @Daij-Djan like this? http://s7.postimg.org/jcq38lhyz/Screen_Shot_2014_09_04_at_07_06_47.png

Comment: ok, in there you can see that that sprite kit is trying to render stuff but that you are not involved at all... edit the question title, post the trace and also tag with sprite kit - also worthwhile is a google search for parts of the stack trace -- if nothing comes up, id post it as a bug

Comment: but better try to make a minimal example app you can share!

Comment: okay. Problem is that I don't have enough reputation to post images. I will change title and add sprite kit tag.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Maybe you should edit my post? You could also post a picture in there?